# Desktop Application with Flash and Php

Tags: php, html, flash, adobe

I want to develop a desktop application using Adobe Flash remember a desktop not a web application. I want to connect Database (MySQL) to it for which I think I should use Php.

Can I send and receive data from Php files silently means without running the Php file itself.

Is there some method to achieve something like this?

Comment: Agree with Pekka. Remember, PHP is a command line programme - it just happens that most people use it via a web server.

Comment: A desktop application. Remember, a desktop application. An application for the desktop. Got that everybody?

Comment: maybe you all are right folks but i found something resembling to which I want. Its called Php GTK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly it sounds like your best bet is going to be to use Adobe AIR. You can use the NativeProcess API to call PHP on the host computer, but you also have the option to use a SQLLite database directly from AIR with no need to mess with PHP.

Here's a link to a sample project with source code provided, this may help. Good luck!

http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/04/07/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some method to achieve something like this?

There are ways to package an Apache/PHP/mySQL environment into an executable, but they are terribly complex to set up and not especially light-weight.

You are probably much better off doing this on a native platform for desktop applications. Every major programming platform has the means to connect to a mySQL database - if that really is the database of choice for a desktop app.